# How do I schedule an update query in PostgreSQL for Windows?

Tags: windows, postgresql, cron

Is it possible to create some sort of function or trigger in PostgreSQL to update a columns field in regards to the time?

For instance today I want the field to equal 1, in 10 hours I want it to equal 0.

Is this possible?

Comment: My database and server is on a windows 7 machine not ready to use linux/unix machine as of yet.

Comment: Well, you can create a task scheduler job to run a cmd.exe script that uses `psql`, or a perl script with DBI, or ...

Comment: (BTW, you should really mention your host OS, exact PostgreSQL version, etc in the text.)

Answer (score 1):

If the value is a function of the time only then it can be calculated at query time. This will always be 0 or 1:

```
select (extract(hour from current_time) >= 12)::int * 1;
 ?column? 
----------
        0
```

Or added to a view:

```
create view v as
select *, (extract(hour from current_time) >= 12)::int * 1
from t;
```

Comment: I was assuming that a view had already been excluded as an option, but really should've mentioned it in my comment anyway. Thanks.